# Description for a workflow in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to have a short comment/description for the job/workflow other than the name of the same.

sometimes it is difficult to identify the purpose or what it does just with the name when we have multiple jobs/workflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put comments in the yaml file or put a readme.md in the workflow folder...

```
# this is a comment in yaml
```

There is no description yaml element to store stuff in.

Comment: would have been good, if there is a description yaml element, that shows a short info about the workflow in UI - Actions tab

Comment: Agreed @smootherbug, Not everyone using GitHub Actions necessarily has permissions or knowledge to read over code files. We use GH Actions to save users that very need.

Answer (score 1):

For workflow, you can try the [`run-name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name) configuration, which allows the use of `github, inputs, vars` contexts. For example

```yaml
run-name: Generate PGP keys for ${{github.repository}} using ${{inputs.PACKAGER_NAME || github.actor}} as identifier
```

For jobs, make use of the [`name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idname) property. This one has access to the `github, needs, strategy, matrix, vars, inputs` contexts. So you can do something like:

```yaml
name: Setup build environment for creating packages at ${{github.repository}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `run` workflow, you can just `echo` something to the console.